# Do VPS nameservers have to be based on real domains

Tags: vps, nameserver

I am curious after I read in this post that the vps's hostname can be arbitrary named and does not need to be based on a real registered domain [Some questions regarding Hostname](https://serverfault.com/questions/319791/some-questions-regarding-hostname).

Is it possible also to have a nameserver name that does not contain a real registered domain?  For example, using `ns1.not-a-reg-domain.com` and a real IP address as a nameserver to be used at gdaddy.

If that can be done, is the second step then is as easy as to set up a zone file for `ns1.not-a-reg-domain.com` using "Add a DNS zone" in WHM/cpanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since people voted this down without offering any concrete explanation, I am going to answer it according to my understanding of the system.  I hope another noob finds it useful. It is long, but it also helps me understand the convention.

Let's say you registered the domain `abc123.com`, the "com" is the top level domain, the "abc123" part is the second level domain.

When a web user wants to visit `abc123.com`, he types in `abc123.com` into his web browser. The browser then contact the DNS resolver (such as google DNS, level3, or opendns -- which is acting as a cache) to query if the DNS resolver has the IP address for `abc123.com` previously saved. If some one had tried to reach `abc123.com` previously through this resolver, the resolver should have the IP address for the `abc123.com` domain name and return the IP to the browser. But if no has ever queried the DNS resolver for `abc123.com`, the resolver does not have the IP cached. The resolver then need to contact the root DNS server for that information.

The root DNS server gets its info from the domain registrars. When you register the `abc123.com` domain, `abc123.com` is recorded by the root DNS server; along with the nameservers/IP (optional).

The guess is that the "`abc123.com`" must exist in the root DNS server for it be able to logically say that `ns1.abc123.com` to be valid. If `abc123.com` does not exist in the record, then `ns1.abc123.com` must not be valid.

Aside from the DNS principle, it is not possible for you to set nameserver names that contains a non registered domain because your registrar won't allow it. If you own `abc123.com` and you log into your registrar to register nameserver names, the top (".com") and second ("abc123") level domains are locked and can't be changed. You can only enter values for the sub level domain. So what you could end up with is `xxxx.abc123.com` as your nameserver name; `abc123.com` is fixed.  So it is not possible to create a public nameserver name that contains an unregistered second-level domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Domain Name System (DNS) is used to denote the location of a computer or resource on the Internet and, as such, requires a fully qualified domain name (FQDN).

To resolve properly, you can "register" name servers with the registrar for a domain name that you own.

For example, you could tell your registrar "I want ns1.mydomain.com to point to the IP 12.23.34.56" and then set the A records for your domain name to match those custom nameservers.

It's a two step process:

1. Register name servers (ns1, ns2, ns3, etc.) that point to the appropriate IP
2. Create A records for those nameservers that point to the appropriate IP

Comment: Thanks Trent, I understand your point 99%, what I am trying to get at is whether I can register a custom "ns1.randomword-not-a-real-domain.com" at the registrar as a nameserver and have it points to an appropriate IP. I am guessing that the answer is yes, but I am not sure.

Comment: No, it needs to be a valid domain name for that.